# AppleScript, copying files

Tags: json, fonts, copy, applescript, directory-structure

I'm trying to copy fonts and a json file to specific destinations, but I get a script error: (Finder got an error: Can’t get folder "Retina—Mid 2014:Users:Me:Library:Application Support:SMuFL:Fonts". )

Here's my script:

```
tell application "Finder"

    set OTF to folder "myproduct:FONTS" of desktop
    set META to folder "myproduct:JSON" of desktop


    set FNT to folder (((path to home folder) as text) & "Library:Fonts")
    set JSN to folder (((path to home folder) as text) & "Library:Application Support:SMFL:Fonts")


    duplicate every file of OTF to FNT with replacing
    duplicate every file of META to JSN with replacing
end tell
```

To know, JSON is a folder containing a folder named ABC, ABC folder contains  a .json file named Papa.json

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Does the folder exist ? The path in your script is different to the path in your error message, so at least one of these is incorrect. _Finder_ ought not to be used to file system operations: it's cumbersome, slow and unreliable. [On a side-note, HFS folder paths should end with a colon, which you've omitted in all instances.]  _System Events_ is more appropriate. You can first check the folder path in question is accessible for reading by running this line of code: `tell application id "com.apple.SystemEvents" to return the folder "~/Library/Application Support/SMFL/Fonts/"`